# Disposition: Parsing

Tags: parsers

I have to prepare 30 minutes of oral examen about the subject called parsing. Where I have to talk about it. And then I shall hand in like 30 pages (including code and figures etc).

I don't know how to structure it and what I can talk about. So what I really need is a disposition! What I have thought about this far:

1. Languages
2. Operation on formal languages
3. Regular Expressions
4. DFA/NFA (+ from NFA to DFA; minimizing DFA)
5. Regular languages
6. Stack automaton
7. Context-free grammar
8. LL grammar
9. Compiler
10. Bottom-up
11. Top-down

But I honestly don't know if that is a good structure? Does all these subject fit under the subject "parsing"? And what would you tell about a compiler? Where would you show some code and how?

I don't ask you to do the work for me, it would just help me enormously if you could help me write a disposition so I can get started.

Comment: Hi, just a quick side remark: If you have 30 minutes then I think your list of topics is way too long. Doing the math says that on average you have less than 3 minutes per topic, which probably will not suffice if you plan to go into detail at all. I routinely underestimate the time for my talks so I might be a bit biased here, but at least it is something to consider.

Comment: I don't know if this helps you at all, but personally I think it is way more interesting to talk about what the parse *does* (i.e., what its purpose and results are), and what you would normally do with those results. As I have probably commented way too often, if someone asks you to talk about trigonometry, you don't start by explaining the Taylor expansion for the computation of the sine function.